# How to mask some digit using SQL Select

Tags: sql-server, string

I have a column named Number

Suppose a value is 12345678997
and I want to output as *******8997, that means all leading digits will be masked by * except the last 4 digits

how can I achieve this using SQL Server Select ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything, I suggest looking at `STUFF`. You'll want `LEN` (and probably `REPLICATE`) as well if your value can have varying lengths

Comment: @blackCat do you have a consistent record in your database in terms of lenght ot it varies?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @i bigint = '12345678997'

select stuff(@i,1,len(@i)-4,'*******')

Output:

*******8997
```

Comment: What about the value like `1234557`? We don't know (at the moment) if the OP's values have a consistent length.

Answer (score 1):

Using [REPLICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql) you can generate a string with a given number of the same character.

Then just add the last four digits to that.

```
select 
Number,
concat(replicate('*',len(Number)-4), right(Number,4)) as MaskedNumber
from YourTable
```