# How to show asterisk or X for all numbers except last 4

Tags: sql-server

I have some sample numbers as below

```
123-456-7890
000-000-0000
```

In sql server how do I show this as below

```
xxx-xxx-0000
***-***-7890
```

Comment: This looks *very* similar to [How to mask some digit using SQL Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356213/how-to-mask-some-digit-using-sql-select)

Comment: If you target SQL Server 2016 and later you should use [dynamic data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2016) to mask the data without adding extra code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this below way-

```
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(100) = '123-456-7890'

SELECT 'xxx-xxx-' + RIGHT(@Number,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use STUFF

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(12) = '123-456-7890'

SELECT STUFF(@string,1,8,'xxx-xxx-')
```